# How to return a value from a void method using Mock setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

How to return a value from a void method using Mock callback

In my unit test I have to mock call to DB write call method. This method is of void type, but for my test assert i need to verify one of the parameters being passed to this method.
Is there a way to return this parameter on mock setup?

Here is my code.

```
public virtual void InsertOrUpdateBrewedEntity(RawDataLeaf theRawData, //this parameter i want to check for assertion
                                                  XsdInfo allXsdInfo = null,
                                                  DbWritingActionCode actionCode = DbWritingActionCode.I,
                                                  Dictionary<string, string> dataIdMap = null,
                                                  Action<string, RawDataLeaf> testActionToDoInsteadOfWriting = null,
                                                  string transactionName = null,
                                                  bool skipValidationEvenForTypesThatCantSaveIfNotValid = false,
                                                  bool disableExtraSqlForXsdType = false,
                                                  string nameOverride = null)
    {
        //code
    }
```

So i want to get value of RawDataLeaf theRawData object on mock method setup.

Here is how i setup this mock method call.

```
_xmlCupboardWriteAccess.Setup(x => x.InsertOrUpdateBrewedEntity(It.IsAny<RawDataLeaf>(),
                                                                 It.IsAny<XsdInfo>(),
                                                                 It.IsAny<DbWritingActionCode>(),
                                                                 It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>(),
                                                                 It.IsAny<Action<string, RawDataLeaf>>(),
                                                                 It.IsAny<string>(),
                                                                 It.IsAny<bool>(),
                                                                 It.IsAny<bool>(),
                                                                 It.IsAny<string>()));
```

Comment: You can't return data from a void, that is what it means. You could maybe use the  out (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) keyword.

Comment: @Bonzo I would prefer to have a solution that does not require me to change signature of the method I am mocking. As a QA i am allowed to write tests but not change implemented code. But thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just verifying the method was called with a particular value, so use `It.Is<>` in your `Verify` call:

```
_xmlCupboardWriteAccess.Verify(x => x.InsertOrUpdateBrewedEntity(
    It.Is<RawDataLeaf>(actualRawDataLeaf => /* your equality test */),
    It.IsAny<XsdInfo>(),
    // ... etc
```

Comment: implemented the way you suggested but getting an exception "Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed"

Comment: @RahulLodha You still need the call to `Setup` that you have in your question.  This just verifies that it was invoked with the right arguments.

Answer (score 0):

moq.Verify() will do the job for you.

https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

// Called at least once
mock.Verify(foo => foo.Execute("ping"), Times.AtLeastOnce());